# Mono is crashing after the process starts

Tags: .net, mono

I have a .net application running on mono 4.0.2 in ubuntu 14.04.

Mono sometimes crashes after the application starts. I see this error in the logs.

```
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4b20bc]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5086ee]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x428f7d]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7ff5ed8c5340]
    [0x7ff5d80cf480]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
```

Let me know, if this is a bug in mono or if this needs to be handled at an application level.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unmanaged exception, that is, a crash inside the runtime, which should never happen.

Please create a minimal testcase that can show this behaviour, and attach it to a bug report here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/